# How to disable Ajax requests from a loaded page with Selenium API

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am reading and parsing a page with Java and Selenium, using the PhantomJSDriver. So far so good. When the page is loaded every 30 seconds a Ajax call is executed from one of the included scripts of this loaded page.

My Question: Is there a way to stop execute certain or any async Javascript requests, at least maybe temporary?

The problem I am having is if I am not done with "parsing" the page before this 30 seconds WebElements become stale and i need to start again...

Comment: i think instead of disabling Ajax requests on the page why don't you try to handle stale element exception please share the piece of code so that i can help you to do that

Comment: There are cleverer workarounds, but in this case, the simplest thing would be to catch the exceptions if/as/when they happen, and re-perform the lookup.

Answer (score 0):

If it takes more than 30 seconds to parse the page, then you are probably doing it the wrong way.
Anyway if you still wish to disable all the Ajax calls :

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript(
  "var p=window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype; p.open=p.send=p.setRequestHeader=function(){};");
```